# Make grouped UITableView adjust separatorInset on toggling edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Here is sample project: 
https://github.com/over-ukraine/UITableView-contentInset-test.git
I've noticed that `tableView` aligns separator insets on cells' label origin, but entering edit mode leaves this insets unchanged. 
But Apple apps (f.e. mail) adjust separator insets on entering and exiting edit mode.

Of course, I can override `setEditing:animated` and set fixed inset within animation block, but this solution is ugly and doesn't solve the case when cells have different label origins. 
Does anyone have the idea how to make this right way?